# How can I document poor Internet connection as evidence to my ISP

Tags: networking, internet, isp

I've had really crappy Internet service lately, and my ISP doesn't seem that interested in fixing it.

I don't think I have any other options considering where I live (kinda rural).

How can I document the slowness and outright lack of connection that often occurs so I can provide evidence to my ISP? I have Windows, Linux and Mac machines available.

Comment: Asking for tools is off topic so I've modified your question slightly. Take a look at [pathping](http://ss64.com/nt/pathping.html) if you are running Windows. You might also want to take a look at your [DSL line stats](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/frogstats.php).

Comment: I looked around and couldn't see any other Stack Exchange sites that seemed to fit this question. Thanks for the edits and suggestions, will try them out.

Comment: One could use [speedtest-cli](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/speedtest-cli-extras) with a periodically executed python-script like [this](https://gitgud.io/J0s3f/speedtest_cron/blob/master/speedtest_cron) (It only has a German readme - you just need to have some UNIX-system (Ubuntu, Raspbian, OSX) with Python >= 2.5 installed, download/install the script + speedtest-cli, change the paths (and server) in the python-script (`./speedtest_cli/speedtest_cli.py --list` to get a list of servers) to your likings, add a cronjob for the script, and last: use `speedcsv` to generate CSV-tables.)

Answer (score -1):

You can always do speed tests online that'll show; upload, download and ping times. Screen shot those as documentation. Also log into your router (if you know how to do that) and that'll show your upload and download speeds as well.

Comment: I was looking for something that would log the data while I'm not using the computer, rather than having to do it manually, as there are likely more outages/slowness than I'm aware of. Also, I don't know how to log in to my router, unfortunately. I emailed the company behind the router asking about the firmware/driver but never got a response.

Comment: What kind of router is it as well? One your ISP gave you?

Comment: Yeah, some super obscure Norwegian one that I've never heard of: Inteno.

Comment: Generally there are log in credentials on the router somewhere, it'll give you an ip address.. Probably something like 192.168.0.1, or 172.16.0.1 or 10.0.0.1.  If you type that into your browsers search bar and give the correct admin name and password you can configure some things one your router. I would check around in there (I have not used that specific type of router before so it'll all be different). You can look around for logged items. Maybe be able to set an SLA which will give you some more information. Now what speed are you supposed to be getting and what are you actually getting?